# Dynamically preventing Laravel from filling created_at field

Tags: laravel-5

I have a model corresponding to a table with "created_at" and "updated_at" fields.
The default Laravel behavior is OK for my need:

- automatically filling "created_at" on inserts,
- automatically filling "updated_at" on updates.

Great, but for some reason (too long to detail here), I need **in some cases** to disable this feature (I mean **dynamically** disabling it during the code execution).

How can I do?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily turn timestamps off.

```
$user = new User;
$user->timestamps = false;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do an IF whenever that happens that you want not to register the timestamp, do an update that makes the created_at equal to nill.

```
     $phonecode = new Telephone;
     $phonecode->phonenumber = $number;
     $phonecode->code = $code;

    if ($number == $mycreditcard)

    $phonecode->created_at = '';

    $phonecode->save();
```

;

Comment: I thought of it, but doing an update after saving doesn't seem to be a clean way to do it... in the worst case, I'll do so.

Comment: I mean, nothing prevents you from dragging the code snippet a few lines above.